# AWS: Linux/UNIX platform is not available for Reserved Instance at N. Virginia region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-regions, aws-reserved-instances

I have an *EC2* instance running in the *N. Virginia* region. The "*Platform details*" is shown as "*Linux/UNIX*". Now I am trying to purchase a reserved instance after selecting the same platform in the search field. But it is showing: [image: No Reserved Instance found]

Now when I search by the same options on a different region (eg: *Oregon* or *N. California*) the purchase options are coming through. Why?

Besides that, I have noticed another thing in *N. Virginia*. There are options coming with "*Amazon VPC*". What does that mean? How can launch an *EC2* with a Platform like "*Linux/UNIX (Amazon VPC)*"?
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Now when I search by the same options on a different region (eg: *Oregon* or *N. California*) the purchase options are coming through. Why?

Amazon may not always have enough capacity for all platforms in all regions - this is why you're seeing different results.

> There are options with "Amazon VPC" appended. What does that mean?

As per [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-classic-platform.html):

> With EC2-Classic, your instances run in a single, flat network that you share with other customers. With Amazon VPC, your instances run in a virtual private cloud (VPC) that's logically isolated to your AWS account.

---

Use `Linux/UNIX (Amazon VPC)` - nobody should be creating new instances using the `EC2-Classic` platform & is will be retired very soon.